# WordPress: how to return meta with query_posts?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm doing an AJAX request using admin-ajax.php whereby I filter posts based on which check-box is checked. It's working great, although I'm struggling to find a way to return the meta details of each post.

I'm just using query_posts to get my data as below:

```
    function ajax_get_latest_posts($tax){

    $args= array(
        'post_type'=>'course',

    'tax_query' => array(
         array(
        'taxonomy' => 'subject',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $tax
    )
    )

);

$posts=query_posts( $args);


return $posts;
}
```

How would I modify this to also return meta data? I know I can filter the posts by meta data using meta_query, but I just want to display the data in my posts.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query go there and look for `meta_query`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EDIT:

Besides the solution outlined bellow, if you're using WordPress >= 3.5(as you should be :) ), you can simply make use of the magic methods of the WP_Post object.

Basically the WP_Post object(which is what the posts array from pretty much every query result that comes from WP_Query consists of) is using PHP's `__get()` and `__isset()` magic methods. These methods allow you to use properties of an object that are not defined in the object itself.

Here's an example.

```
foreach ( $posts as $key => $post ) {
    // This:
    echo $post->key1;
    // is the same as this:
    echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key1', true );
}
```

If you make a `print_r( $post )` or `var_dump( $post )`, you will not see the "key1" property of the `$post` object. But the function [__get()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7/src/wp-includes/post.php#L648) allows you to access that property.

===========================================================

You have two general options in my opinion - loop through the posts and get the data that you need, like so(this code will go right after `$posts = query_posts( $args );`):

```
foreach ( $posts as $key => $post ) {
    $posts[ $key ]->key1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key1', true );
    $posts[ $key ]->key2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key2', true );
}
```

Or hook to the `the_posts` filter hook and do the same thing there(more work, but if you have multiple functions that need to add that data to each post - it might be easier). This code would go to your functions.php or your plugin's files(if you're making a plugin):

```
function my_the_posts_filter( $posts ) {
    foreach ( $posts as $key => $post ) {
        $posts[ $key ]->key1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key1', true );
        $posts[ $key ]->key2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key2', true );
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

And then you would change your

```
$posts=query_posts( $args);
```

line to this:

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'my_the_posts_filter', 10 );

$posts = query_posts( $args );

remove_filter( 'the_posts', 'my_the_posts_filter', 10 );
```

Considering the fact that this would happen inside of an AJAX request, you can technically get rid of the `remove_filter()` call, but it's good to have it just in case you're going to make any other post queries in your code.

Comment: perfect answer, I ended using the first solution, but the second one is also great as I was unaware of this method. Thank you, you saved me hours

Comment: I updated my answer - I totally forgot about the magic methods of the WP_Post object - they are much more easier to use :). Basically you can just access the meta keys as a property of the object. Feel free to look at the code here - http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7/src/wp-includes/post.php#L648 and see what other stuff you can access like that(for instance `$post->page_template` ;) )

Comment: great, thanks! Haven't used WP_Post yet, it does look a bit simpler. thanks for the modification, good luck with Paiyak